# How can I limit each file's diff in a git diff output

Tags: git

I'd like to limit the diff of each file.

For example: I have 2 files that have changed.
1 file has 1000 diffs while the 2nd file has 5 diffs.
I'd like to see only a 100 diffs from file 1
but all 5 diffs from file 2.

One solution is to get a list of files that have changed and then 
foreach file do 
    diff | head 100

But would be cool to ask git to do that for me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think git diff allows this. So I guess you answered your own question:

```
for f in `git diff --name-only`; do git diff $f | head -n100; done
```